# Laravel 4 multi-language error messages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, error-handling

is there an easy way to provide error messages in different ways? This is my code to show an error view:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    $error = array(
        'code' => $code,
        'id' => 'Error',
        'title' => 'Not found',
        'message' => 'The requested site was not found!'
    );

    if (!Config::get('app.debug'))
    {
        return Response::view('pages.errors.default', $error, $code);
    }
});
```

As you can see, I create an array holding all the relevant information about an error (I just added some test data yet). But my application supports two languages. Is there something like an errors.php file in Laravel?

If not, what might be the best place to store my error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes see [Laravel Localization](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization)  you can create a file errors.php and put the error messages in the file

```
return array(
    'title' => 'Not found',
    'message' => 'The requested site was not found!'
);
```

in

```
 /app
     /lang
         /en
             errors.php
         /yourlanguage
             errors.php
```

and call it using

```
echo Lang::get('errors.title');
echo Lang::get('errors.message');
```

note that **errors** is your filename